# How to print the contents of the datagridview in windows form application c#,Without truncating the characters in GRID?

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

I have an windows application written in c#.In my application am showing the data using DataGridView.I want to print all the contents of the data as table while clicking the print button.For now it prints the all the row.But inside the column of the table it truncating the values of the data shown in the GRID view.
How to achieve this??

Comment: I would write a generic function which takes the DataGridView and creates an html file with table exactly according to the columns, rows, headers and cell values of your DataGridView + some nice CSS for formatting the table. Then you may show a print preview of your data in a WebBrowser control or in external web browser, and then the user may print or save the generated report using the web browser capabilities - including exporting the html to Word or Excel. And it would work for any grid in your application.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: No, I do not have it currently (it was done for some project), but it is just 2 nested 'for' loops - by rows and by columns - writing <tr> and <td> with cell contents inside the <td>.

Comment: Thanks for your information